# One-liner to find a registry key and delete parent works but returns an error

Tags: powershell

I am using a one liner to find a registry key based on a value then delete it's parent. The one liner produces an error but if I separate the search result into a variable and run remove-item there is no error. I'd like to find out what causes this and if I should I be worried?

Produces an error:

```
Get-ChildItem -path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Products -Recurse -ErrorAction Stop  | Get-ItemProperty -Name "PackageName" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue| where { $_.PackageName -cmatch "BigFixAgent\.msi" } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty PSParentPath | Remove-Item -Recurse -confirm
```

> ```
> Get-ChildItem : The registry key at the specified path does not exist.
> At line:1 char:1
> + Get-ChildItem -path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Products -Recurs ...
> + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (HKEY_LOCAL_MACH...4D34\SourceList:String) [Get-ChildItem],
> ArgumentException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
> ```

Produces No Errors:

```
$offending_key= Get-ChildItem -path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Products -Recurse -ErrorAction Stop  | Get-ItemProperty -Name "PackageName" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue| where { $_.PackageName -cmatch "BigFixAgent\.msi" } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty PSParentPath

Remove-Item -Recurse $offending_key -confirm
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because it is iterating recursively through the registry tree, and you deleted part of that tree in the middle of the iteration. You could put parenthesis around everything but the last part, so that it finishes iteration first, or you could put the last part in a `ForEach-Object` loop, and add a break after it so once that key is found it removes it and stops looking.

Complete `Get-ChildItem` iteration before deleting:

```
(Get-ChildItem -path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Products -Recurse -ErrorAction Stop  | Get-ItemProperty -Name "PackageName" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue| where { $_.PackageName -cmatch "BigFixAgent\.msi" } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty PSParentPath) | Remove-Item -Recurse -confirm
```

Stop after finding the first matching key:

```
Get-ChildItem -path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Products -Recurse -ErrorAction Stop  | Get-ItemProperty -Name "PackageName" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue| where { $_.PackageName -cmatch "BigFixAgent\.msi" } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty PSParentPath | ForEach-Object {$_ | Remove-Item -Recurse -confirm; break}
```

Comment: Thank you! I had a feeling that was what was happening but I couldn't wrap my head around how to make it work without the error in a single line.

Comment: By the way, it looks like the second line of code you posted doesn't work, and I'm pretty sure it's because the `Select-Object -ExpandProperty PSParentPath` is used, which I think it passes a string through the pipe instead of an object but even when I add a `| Get-ChildItem |` inbetween the `Select-Object` and the `ForEach` statement I get:
`cmdlet Remove-Item at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Path[0]:`

Comment: You're right, I passed the iteration to the `Remove-Item` cmdlet, so it should work as expected now.